# Why is my SendGrid function returning "Service Unavailable"?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I am new to SendGrid and trying to send am email from my React.js app using Firebase Cloud functions for my backend.
When someone wants to send a message, I write a document to Firestore. I then listen to that collection and when a document is created I send an email from a cloud function.

I'm trying to make it work, but keep getting an error logged in my cloud functions and this error message:

```
Error: Service Unavailable
    at axios.then.catch.error (node_modules/@sendgrid/client/src/classes/client.js:133:29)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

EDIT: I've caught the error in a catch statement, and got more details about it. This is the full log:

```
{ Error: Forbidden
    at axios.then.catch.error (node_modules/@sendgrid/client/src/classes/client.js:133:29)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
  code: 403,
  message: 'Forbidden',
  response: 
   { headers: 
      { server: 'nginx',
        date: 'Thu, 11 Jun 2020 17:03:27 GMT',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'content-length': '281',
        connection: 'close',
        'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io',
        'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
        'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl',
        'access-control-max-age': '600',
        'x-no-cors-reason': 'https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html' },
     body: { errors: [Array] } } }
```

EDIT 2:
So I've follow the link in the error `https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/cors/` and if I get that right, it suggests that it blocks me because I am trying to make a browser-based call to their API? But that's not the case. I'm making the call from a cloud function.

I can't figure out if I'm doing anything wrong, or am I just unlucky and have been trying to implement it for the first time while SendGrid is experiencing some issues (`Service Unavailable`).

This is how I define sgMail:

```
import * as sgMail from "@sendgrid/mail";
const SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgridfull.key;
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);
```

This is my cloud function, and I've checked all the variables and they all exist.

```
exports.firestoreEmail = functions.firestore
  .document("email_messages/{messageID}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const msgData = snap.data();
    if (!msgData) return;

    return db
      .collection("users")
      .doc(msgData.recipient_ID)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        const recipientData = doc.data();
        if (!recipientData) return;

        const promises: any = [];

        const msg = {
          to: recipientData.email,
          from: msgData.sender_email,
          templateId: "d-myRandomTemplateId",
          dynamic_template_data: {
            sender_name: "Some One",
          },
        };

        const msg2 = {
          to: msgData.sender_email,
          from: recipientData.email,
          templateId: "d-myRandomTemplateId",
          dynamic_template_data: {
            sender_name: "Some One",
          },
        };



        promises.push(sgMail.send(msg));
        promises.push(sgMail.send(msg2));

        return Promise.all(promises);
      });
  });
```

Comment: What is your pricing plan? You need to be on the "Blaze" pricing plan.

As a matter of fact, the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services". See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (hover your mouse on the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title)

Since Sendgrid is not a Google-owned service, you need to switch to the "Blaze" plan.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thank you for your comment. I am on the Blaze plan on my Firebase project, free plan in SendGrid

Comment: Ok, how do you define `sgMail`?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Edited my question with that info

Comment: Seems correct! What is strange is that you get an axios error... Axios is normally not involved in your Cloud function... Any idea? Any other piece of code using axios?

Comment: Yeah I know! No idea, I don't use Axios at all in my app. Maybe it is an issue with SendGrid? Or does this imply it's something with me? Can't quite understand where this points to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215745/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-tsabary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [github issue](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/1090#issuecomment-620123775) where it specifies how to use sgMail.send method which is causing the Cloud Function to return Service Unavailable error.

The send and sendMultiple methods return a Promise, so you can handle success and capture errors:

```
sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then(() => {
    // Celebrate
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Log friendly error
    console.error(error);

    if (error.response) {
      // Extract error msg
      const {message, code, response} = error;

      // Extract response msg
      const {headers, body} = response;

      console.error(body);
    }
  });
```

Alternatively, you can pass a callback function as the last parameter:

```
sgMail
  .send(msg, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      // Do something with the error
    }
    else {
      // Celebrate
    }
  });
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me figure out my issue. For my 'from' field I've set an email that wasn't set as an authorized sender